# Jquery is not working on html echoed by php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I `echo` my html in the body using php.
Like this:

```
<body>
<?php
echo " <button type=\"button\" id=\"button\">Click Me!</button> ";
?>
</body>
```

In this html I have a button with the id set to `button`. Then, in Jquery,I have this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
    alert("It works");
    });
    });
```

However, *It works* is not getting printed. What should I do?

Comment: document ready handler....

Comment: @PranavCBalan I have included it. Still nothing.

Comment: Do you see errors in your developer console?

Comment: Did you include jQuery ?

Comment: Oh guys, I fund it. I saw the developer console and I was missing a } so the javascript was not being executed.. :(

Comment: Where did you include jQuery, is it at the bottom of the page before the closing `</body>`? If not, try moving it there.

Comment: I include jQuery in the <head>.But.. it is working now. I was just missing a }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It also depends on where your Javascript Code is located within the DOM and also if you have jQuery included in the page in question.

Something like this could hopefully work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous">

    </script>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <?php
                echo " <button type=\"button\" id=\"button\">Click Me!</button> ";
            ?>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#button").on("click", function(e){
                    alert("It works");
                });
            });

        })(jQuery);
    </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Please note that the above Snippet is assumed to live inside a PHP File (index.php - for example).